# Valid set of options in nmake

Tags: visual-studio-2010, visual-studio-debugging, nmake

I have an application that compiles fine with nmake.  But it does not compile in debug mode. So I edited    .mak file and added /Debug for "link" options and "Zi" for "cl.exe" options. During compilation it looks like this now:         cl  -I ../../../  -DEXTRACT_ONLY  -DNO_READ_FROM_CODER  -D_SFX -Gr -c -FoO/ -WX -EHsc -Gy -GR- /Zi -MT -W4 -GS- -Zc:forScope -O1 -Yu"StdAfx.h" -FpO/a.pch abc.cpp 
and I get this error: 
error C2855: command-line option '/Zi' inconsistent with precompiled header

Q1: Can I simply remove options like -Yu or -Fpo and it will still work ( though take longer to compile because there is no recompiled stuff now)? 
Q2. Is there an option of nmake to clean all files generated by it. ( I am using .mak files )
Note: I am in vs2010 world.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answer to Q1: I removed  -Yu and -Fpo and it compiled. Now I am able to debug.  Note that Q2 still remain unanswered.